# CF Report Builder displaying html tags (ie rich text) as plain text

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-8, cfml, coldfusionbuilder, coldfusion-7

This is the content from the database:

```
<p><b>As the newly reborn Modbook Inc.</b> </p>
```

The actual output in the report page is the same (including the html tags).

```
<p><b>As the newly reborn Modbook Inc.</b> </p>
```

The expected output was bold text like:

**As the newly reborn Modbook Inc.**

Comment: I ran into similar issues. as noted by @travis, Kay Smoljak does mention that only some html tags are supported. I have filed a bug with adobe about it at https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=3861021.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I've seen you'll need to use a [custom function](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/130228-using-html-in-cfreport-builder-data/). It looks like someone was trying to use that solution as recent as 19 March 2012.  I see [here on Kay Smol­jak's blog](http://kay.smoljak.com/2006/04/coldfusion-report-builder-sanity-saving-tips/) that there is a property to handle some of the tags but I haven't tested it (and it's from almost 7 years ago, however considering the lack of popularity in report builder I doubt Adobe's done much to help the issue).

> **The mys­te­ri­ous HTML For­mat­ted Text property**
>
> The lat­est build of the Report Builder included a new prop­erty for
>   text objects – HTML For­mat­ted Text (true or false). It’s not in the
>   pro­gram help or in the live­docs. Basic HTML that I tried –
>   para­graphs, Hx ele­ments and strong ele­ments – didn’t seem to work –
>   the markup showed in the ren­dered report. Through a process of trial
>   and error, I dis­cov­ered that  ele­ments do work. Other
>   presentation-style HTML such as the  ele­ment prob­a­bly also work.

Comment: The function in 
http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/130228-using-html-in-cfreport-builder-data/

is removing the html tags. But I need to format the text same way it the web page.

Comment: @rejithrkrishnan yeah, I think that's because report builder seems to wrap all the output in a `HTMLEditFormat` type function, like it or not.

Answer (score 1):

1. Use `<strong>` instead of `<b>`.
2. Use `<i>` instead of `<em>`.
3. Use `<a href="http://www.someLocation.com">http://www.someLocation.com</a>` instead of `<a href="http://www.someLocation.com">some English here</a>`.
4. Don't use `&nbsp;`. It crashes. I don't have good work-arounds for this.
5. Don't use `<hr>`. It crashes. I don't have good work-arounds for this.

You might find more at as adobe looks into it at https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=3861021.